# Trouble Projecting a linq Query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, projection

I have the following entity model :

[image]

And from it I need data in a format like :

```
Name, Picked, Packed, Complaints
ie Name=Muhammad Picked=6 Packed=9 Complaints=1
```

Within a given time period (using ProcessedOn).

I have the following complex looking query (for me).

```
        using(var db = new DbContainer())
        {
            var workers =
                db.Workers.Select(
                    x => new
                            {
                                x.Name,
                                Picked = x.PickedOrders.Where(a => a.ProcessedOn >= dtStart.Value && a.ProcessedOn <= dtEnd.Value).Sum(y => y.Units),
                                Packed = x.PackedOrders.Where(a => a.ProcessedOn >= dtStart.Value && a.ProcessedOn <= dtEnd.Value).Sum(y => y.Units),
                                Complaints = x.PickedOrders.Where(a => a.ProcessedOn >= dtStart.Value && a.ProcessedOn <= dtEnd.Value).Count(y => y.Complaint != null) 
                                    + x.PackedOrders.Where(a => a.ProcessedOn >= dtStart.Value && a.ProcessedOn <= dtEnd.Value).Count(y => y.Complaint != null)
                            }).ToList();
        }
```

I get this error :

**The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.**

Any ideas?

Comment: ProcessedOn is nullable. But even if I use ProcessedOn.Value >= its the same error.

Comment: Try GetValueOrDefault(0) instead of Value.